# He loved painting and writing

Tags: adverbs, conjunctions

He loved painting and writing, ___ he chose to become an engineer.

1. for
2. so
3. therefore
4. yet

I am stuck here because I think option 2. works if that is civil or architectural engineering. And I think option 4. works because writing is not related to engineering.

Comment: 'Yet' because it shows the contradiction among the choices of the person. Also it is 'therefore' and not 'therefor'. I believe it is a typo.

Answer (score 2):

It is not mentioned what type of engineer we are talking about, so I think the best option will be *"yet"* as it *contradicts with* the previous clause.

The option "so" can be debatable, but we should stick with pragmatics here.

Answer (score 2):

"Yet" meaning "nevertheless; in spite of that."

Even with civil or architectural engineering, the chances to write and paint are much less than becoming a writer or a painter.

Comment: The other "clue" that the question writer intends "yet" is that "so" and "therefore" are synonymous here. If you think that people who like writing and painting are naturally attracted to engineering, you could choose so or therefore.  This ambiguity suggests both are "wrong" (in the mind of the person setting the test)